# Additional htmlAttributes in addition to EditorTemplate MVC 5.2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using an EditorTemplate for localized displaying a DateTimeOffset.

EditorTemplate:

```
@model DateTimeOffset?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLocalTime()
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") : string.Empty), new
    {
        @class = "form-control datetimepicker"
    })
```

This is working correctly when I am using the Html.EditorFor. However, I would like to pass **additional** htmlAttributes to the object in my view.

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidToDate, new { 
    htmlAttributes = new { @data_date_min_date = DateTime.Now.ToString() } 
})
```

The attribute in this example (data_date_min_date) doesn't get rendered. How can I provide additional htmlAttributes to a field that are specific for a certain view?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing this additional data via ViewData dictionary. The `additionalData` parameter of the `Html.EditorFor` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29) takes an anonymous object that will be merged to the view data dictionary. So you may read it from the View data dictionary in your editor template/partial view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidToDate,  
                                    new { data_date_min_date = DateTime.Now.ToString()})
```

and in your editor template

```
@model DateTimeOffset?

<h4>Value passed from main view : @ViewData["data_date_min_date"]</h4>

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLocalTime()
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") : string.Empty), new
    {
        @class = "form-control datetimepicker"
    })
```

Comment: `@ViewData["data_date_min_date"]` does not exist. It is stored in`@ViewData["htmlAttributes"]`.

Comment: No. If you are passing the value of `data_date_min_date` as the way i had shown in the answer it should work. You will pass an object with keys and values. But you were trying to pass an object which has another object in it. I verified this in my machine and it totally works.

Answer (score 0):

As a full answer to my question:

`htmlAttributes` that are defined in the view are passed into the EditorTemplate in the `ViewData["htmlAttributes"]` object. You may pass this into the `Html.TextBox` directly, or supply additional htmlAttributes as I am doing:

```
@model DateTimeOffset?
@{
    RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    string additionalHtmlAttributes = "form-control datetimepicker";
    if (htmlAttributes.ContainsKey("class"))
    {
        htmlAttributes["class"] = String.Format("{0} {1}", htmlAttributes["class"], additionalHtmlAttributes);
    }else
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("class", additionalHtmlAttributes);
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") : string.Empty), htmlAttributes)
```